# For loop and list - syntax

Tags: python

I've got some problem with syntax in python.

Below is a simple example:

Instead that (1):

```
value = []
value.append(int(self.val1.GetValue()))
value.append(int(self.val2.GetValue()))
value.append(int(self.val3.GetValue()))
value.append(int(self.val4.GetValue()))
```

I want do sth like that (2):

```
value = []
for i in range(4):
    value.append(int(self.val + (i + 1) + .GetValue()))
```

But as you see it's an invalid syntax.

The question is what I must correct in above loop to obtain the same resault like in (1)

Comment: sounds like a bad design. why don't you store the values in self as a list?

Comment: maybe its possible to store val* objects in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = [int(v.GetValue()) for v in (self.val1, self.val2, self.val3, self.val4)]
```

would probably be the cleanest way.

Even shorter would be to use something with `getattr(self, 'val%d' % i).GetValue()`, but that's quite ugly.